# XQuery Collection - Cant get multiple files from a directory

Tags: xquery, collect

I'm trying to get all the filenames from a directory that have a specific string in the XML elements. I'm using this code for that:

```
for $x in collection('file:///C:/Sricpts/Software20180101-V1.1.1/workspace/Data_PreProcessing?select=*.xml')
where matches($x, 'INSERT INTO')
return $x
```

However when I run the code it gives that error:

```
[FODC0002] Resource 'C:/Program Files (x86)/BaseX/file:/file:///C:/Sricpts/Software20180101-V1.1.1/workspace/Data_PreProcessing?select=*.xml' does not exist.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which XQuery processor do you use?

Comment: Processor BaseX 9.0.2

Answer (score 1):

If you use BaseX, there is no need to specify a file filter. All XML documents that occur in the specified directory will be added to your collection:

```
for $x in collection('file:///C:/Sricpts/Software20180101- V1.1.1/workspace/Data_PreProcessing')
where matches($x, 'INSERT INTO')
return $x
```

If you want to have more control over the documents to be chosen, you can take advantage of the [File Module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module):

```
let $root := 'C:\Sricpts\Software20180101- V1.1.1\workspace\Data_PreProcessing'
for $path in file:list($root, true(), '*.xml')
let $doc := doc($root || $path)
where matches($doc, 'INSERT INTO')
return $doc
```

Comment: It gives me the same result... it is a problem if I have more sub-folders inside this my directory?

Comment: In that case, the directory you specified does not exist. Maybe it is meant to be `Scripts` instead of `Sricpts`? What about the space before `V1.1.1`? You can also omit the file protocol and use a Windows path (C:\Scripts\...\).

Comment: The thing is: when it opens the file inside the sub-folder it gives to it the orignal directory which is wrong because the file is inside the sub-folder

Comment: Sorry, I can’t follow. Maybe you refer to the confusing path in the error message? All I can say is that the code works fine if your path refers to an existing directory. For more details, I invite you to write to the `basex-talk` mailing list (http://basex.org/about/open-source/).

Comment: Imagine that you have the files inside Directory C:. And together with that files you've multiple sub-folder (for example, scripts folder). Using the current script when it analyze an file (File1, for example) from scripts folder it will give the following directory: C:/File1 which is not correct because it will have to pass the following directory: C:/scripts/File1

Comment: I’m still not sure if I can follow. Did you spend some time to read the documentation of the File Module? As sub-folders were not part of your original question, and as the title and the description of this StackOverflow question is not consistent (are you looking for files or filenames? etc) I still believe this should be discussed somewhere else, preferably on the mailing list.